# Does path.getTotalLength work for text svg?

Tags: javascript, svg, text, stroke

I'm trying to get the path length for the stroke of a SVG text element and I'm getting a `path.getTotalLength is not a function` error in my console. When I look up `getTotalLength`, I see that it's been depreciated? It looks like it has something to do with the shift from SVG1 to SVG2? Is this correct?

Comment: I don't think it never did have this method...

Comment: What do you think the total length of text is? How would you calculate it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has not been deprecated.  In SVG 1.1, `getTotalLength()` is only available on the `<path>` element.

In SVG 2, which browsers are still in the process of implementing (so you can't rely on it yet), `getTotalLength()` is available on all shape elements, but not including text elements.

Comment: is it available on text? SVGTextContentElement inherits from SVGGraphicsElement not form SVGGeometryElement. 
Afaik only the method described in [Annotation 38](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/text.html#DOMInterfaces) will make it possible to use getTotalLength on SVGTextContentElements...

Comment: Cool, thank you. I'm going to look at converting the text to path by hand in Illustrator.

Comment: @HolgerWill Yes. Thanks for catching that. It was a typo. I meant to say "but not text".

Comment: @PaulLeBeau So I got the text ported to a path using Illustrator and I've run document.querySelector('g path') to bind it to var lengthz, and then bound var totalLengthz to lengthz.getTotalLength and then console logged that. I get 172. I'm not quite sure what I'm supposed to do with that number or how to bind it to the animation dasharray info inside my css though. Thank you for any light you can shed on this. I'm searching everywhere for clarification.

Comment: That sounds small. Are you sure you are getting the total length of your all your characters?  You may need to merge all your character paths into one path element.  It might be best to post another question with a working code snippet.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I figured it out. It was a single letter that it was measuring. I wrote a javascript loop to loop through all the letters dynamically. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PaulLeBeau according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getTotalLength) getTotalLength() has been deprecated (from paths as well...from what I can tell), on the other hand - like you mentioned - [SVGGeometryElement.pathLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement) is not very well supported - do you know of an alternative?

Comment: @Danield That deprecated note in MDN is misleading. I suspect it might be an autogenerated message based on the fact that the method is moving to a different interface.  It is definitely not going away altogether.

Comment: To clarify, `getTotalLength()` is **not** deprecated... and if you'd like to be able to get length of an SVG text element, then **please** add a ⭐ to [github issue 221](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/221) (re: *"Provide text-to-path-data conversion method")*