# circle.getTotalLength() Internet explorer error

Tags: javascript, svg, ecmascript-6, microsoft-edge, polyfills

I'm trying to use the method `.getTotalLength()` to get the total length of an svg circle.

```
    const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');

    const totalLength = circle.getTotalLength();
```

In Edge I get the error:

`ReferenceError: 'getTotalLength' is not defined`

For added insight the element is an svg  `<circle>` not a path.

How can I detect in js if this is supported in Edge/ Internet explorer and/or provide a polyfill for it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198953/does-path-gettotallength-no-longer-work-anymore-for-text-svg

Comment: [Browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement#Browser_compatibility). As for detection, it's as simple as `if (circle.getTotalLength) ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you may not use the `getTotalLength` method, since what you have is a circle, you can use the formula for the circle's perimeter **2*Math.PI*r** where `r` is the circle's radius. There is a small difference but I don't think it matters.

```js
console.log("getTotalLength",theCircle.getTotalLength());
let r = Number(theCircle.getAttribute("r")); //circle's radius
console.log("2*Math.PI*r",2*Math.PI*r)
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg>
  <circle id="theCircle" cx="150" cy="75" r="70" />
</svg>
```